# How do I read the kubelet agent information in a k8s cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

For any node, we can just do

```
node, err := clientset.corev1().Node("node_name").Get(...)
```

I am looking for something similar to view the kubelet agent.
`clientset.corev1().Pod` does not have them since it is not managed by api server.

Is there a way to programmatically retrieve this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to programmatically retrieve this information?

No. The kubelet is not a *resource* (e.g. [API resource / object](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/kubernetes-objects/#kubernetes-objects)) in Kubernetes.

Comment: is kubelet complete hidden from users? how can one get metadata for kubelet then?

Comment: Users manage pods in Kubernetes, the underlying infrastructure is abstracted away.